# Advice for how Java classes should be organized

Tags: java, class

I'm fairly new to Java but love it so far. My question is, i'm a little unfamiliar with Classes. I know what they are, and generally how to work with them as I'm not brand new to programming, but I would like a professionals opinion.

I'm currently writing a small multi threading program to launch parallel power shell sessions by spawning cmdlines for target machines in a csv, capture the output and write to a csv.

Should I put everything into one class and breakup the logical operations to methods within the class and string them together? Or should I make a Thread executor class, cmdline powershell class, a csv operations class, etc (My thought behind that was to allow code reuse, but that'll be kindove time consuming and in my mind impractical since i'd have to specify the datatypes and return types for new situations in the future).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A better thing is to follow the standards as possible as you can and separate each group of related data and methods in its own class , I suggest you have a look at this page https://java-design-patterns.com/principles/

Comment: Look up Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: People who have been programming for 10 hours per day for 20 years still struggle with this question, regularly (and they often get it wrong ... the ones who get it wrong less often than the others tend to be paid more, because getting this right is part of your work). As such, I think the question is far, far too broad.

Comment: have a look in this two links :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Answer (score 2):

There is no "way" so to speak,
It's all your preference.

But just don't cram everything into one class.
Generally, you want to be as neat as possible.

In the future, you will thank yourself for using different classes.
If your project grows, and a bug is born, you don't want to be looking through one very long class, but instead simple broken up pieces.

Let's say you have these classes:
    GPS,
    Main,
    Search

And someone reports a bug with the GPS not working.
Instead of looking everywhere saying, where did I put the GPS code,
it's right in front of your eyes!

Answer (score 0):

I've went to everyones links and found the info very helpful. So far I've come up with this.

1. Make a package that contains classes that perform a specific set of tasks (also don't make utility kits that are very general). The package in my case would be called com.jt.threads.powershell or something.
2. Keep classes small and breakup the program by conceptual types. (ie. data reading and writing operations on a filesystem should be in one class with the focus on helping the package perform a certain task or range of tasks.)
3. Methods within classes should focus on getting, setting, changing the objects attributes or adding logic.
4. The program entry point should join it all together, except in the case of large applications, in which case an interface should be used (still learning about them).

With true OOP, i don't think it's a good idea to create code for reuse, unless it's supporting a range of very very very similar tasks (that way if I have to change something, it won't break other classes outside of the package).

Thank you all! I feel a lot better knowing that I'm on the right track. I was worried that by NOT making code reusable in a lot of situations that I was doing something wrong. I started programming in Python 6 months ago for my job, but I totally ignored classes and I want to have good programming habits and apply OOP as best I can going forward! Python is definitely convenient and a great starter language, but I wish I learnt Java first so I can get a solid grasp on OOP.

Answer (score -1):

There is no “The way” to organize or group classes. Anything goes as long as it works as expected and you understand what you write.

As a Programmer you only need to, 
1. Know and understand what you write.
2. Know and understand what other Programmer as written.

Comment: I would add: facilitate the task of other programmers knowing and understanding what you have written, Which basically means to use proper programming patterns (which definitely includes proper class organisation).